# How can I expose metrics with spark framework?

Tags: rest, monitoring, prometheus, spark-java

I'm using spark framework (http://sparkjava.com).

I need to expose metrics in order to use with prometheus.

for example I have a get request:

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> 1000);
```

How can I now expose the metrics ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prometheus provides client library for java, [Client_java](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java). You can integrate it with your framework.

Here is a working [example](https://gist.github.com/tazjin/52b7b93fb54fccb9efb9628b471122e3).